# how to disconnect socket.io after touch another tab react native

Tags: react-native, socket.io, navigation, react-navigation

I have 5 buttom tabs in react-native app. on each screen i want to connect socket to different namespaces like `io.of('/home')` or `io.of('/shop')` or else.

how can I disconnect user from current socket when he switch tabs. I could not find anything on react-navigation doc.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `socket.disconnect()` to disconnect your current socket in your switching tab function.